# Save Beautiful Soup page structure in tree form with strings

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, extract

I need to save the HTML structure in a **tree form** of Beautiful Soup 4, in Python 3.4, where I **keep the indentation of each open node**. For this, I am doing the following:

```
# Store the current depth
depth = 0
current = None
content = dict()

# For each children
for child in self.soup.recursiveChildGenerator():
  # If is a tag
  if child.name is not None:
    # Append to content at current level
    if depth == 0:
      if child.name.lower() in content:
        current = content[child.name.lower()]
      else:
        current = content[child.name.lower()] = dict()
    else:
      if child.name.lower() in current:
        current = current[child.name.lower()]
      else:
        current = current[child.name.lower()] = dict()
    # Increase depth
    depth += 1

  # leaf node
  elif not child.isspace():
    # Reset depth
    depth = 0
```

But when a try to parse a complex page like [Terra - Brazil Biggest Portal](http://terra.com.br), will return something like that:

```
{'link': {}, 'li': {}, 'ul': {}, 'meta': {}, 'div': {}, 'body': {}, 'html': {}}
```

What I want is something like:

```
{
  html: {
    body: {
      ul: {
        li: {
          a: ['Li #1', 'Li #2', 'Li #3']
        }
      },
      nav: {
        ul: {
          li: {
            a: ['Other Li #1', 'Other Li #2']
          }
        }
      },
      article: {
        p: ['Hello world', 'Hello world 2', 'Lorem ipsum']
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**I believe my approach is completely wrong**, but I can not think of the proper solution, or may have to **change the way you save the data**.

Comment: What is wrong with using a proper DOM tree instead of trying to hand-craft a dictionary-list-mashup-representation of something which is neither?

Comment: Have a look at **Xpath** btw, which will allow you to query the document using path expressions such as `//ul/li//a` to get all links in every list.

Comment: have a look at http://www.xavierdupre.fr/blog/2013-10-27_nojs.html